# Excel COM: Prevent auto calculate cells when opening workbook

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, vba

I have a workbook in which the calculation of cells is set to automatic. This means that calculation will start when I open the workbook.

How can I prevent the calculation to start when I open the workbook?

NB: I Know I can stop it *after* the workbook has been opened, but then one or more cells can be changed already in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the [Workbook Event(s)](http://www.excel-pratique.com/en/vba/workbook_events.php) to execute different actions based on an event that occurs (change, selection, activation, etc) in your workbook. Then you can set the workbook calculation to manual.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End Sub
```